# Session Storage and localstorage in react native

Tags: react-native, session, expo, local-storage

Expo SecureStore is more like localstoarge !
if yes how to save in session stoarge i need explanation
btw AsyncStorage is Removed from react native documentation

i expect libs or documentation to use to save in session and localstoarge

Comment: Expo SecureStore docs are [here](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/securestore/) and async storage was removed from react native and place in a separate library [here](https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/api/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [@react-native-async-storage/async-storage](https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/install/), it's the same logic as localstoarge